# javascript how to add comma between special characters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string which I would like to use in an array.
My string looks like this:

```
[[30.251449,-97.893596][30.406576,-98.057163][30.370589,-97.946591][30.362589,-97.981294]]
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
[[30.251449,-97.893596],[30.406576,-98.057163],[30.370589,-97.946591],[30.362589,-97.981294]]
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.replace can do that

```
str = str.replace(/\]\[/g, '],[');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J26qm/)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all instances of "][" with "], [", like this:

```
var myString = "[[30.251449,-97.893596][30.406576,-98.057163][30.370589,-97.946591][30.362589,-97.981294]];"
var validJSON = myString.replace(/\]\[/g, "], [");

// To get actual arrays:
var arrays = JSON.parse(validJSON);
```

Edit: previous way would only replace one occurrence